# using WRL to access winRT: where do you find the right names to use for the classfactories and classes?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2022, wrl

(This is the next iterative question so I can figure out how to use WRL, after [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595142/using-wrl-to-access-winrt-i-cannot-get-activateinstance-to-work) was answered I believe correctly.)

So I'm trying to build up to being able to access Bluetooth LE devices through WinRT via WRL.

Continuing in the pattern of a [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/how-to-activate-and-use-a-windows-runtime-component-using-wrl?view=msvc-170) (which is for the uri WinRT class), I am trying at this point just to get the class factory for the DeviceWatcher Class.  ( [Documentation for that class seems to be here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-22000) ), this is my pared-down example code:

```
#include <roapi.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.foundation.h>
#include <windows.foundation.collections.h>
#include <wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <windows.devices.enumeration.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;

using namespace ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;

int dummy;

ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClassFactory> uriFactory;
ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClass> uri;

ComPtr<IDeviceWatcherRuntimeClassFactory> devWatcherFactory;  //This line produces the only error, "IDeviceWatcherRuntimeClassFactory undefined"
                                                              //(When the line is omitted, the code compiles, links, and produces the smart pointer to a uri class) 
HRESULT hr, hr2, hr3;
    
int main()
{
   
    // Initialize the Windows Runtime.
    RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
  
    // Get the activation factory for the IUriRuntimeClass interface.
    ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClassFactory> uriFactory;
    HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Foundation_Uri).Get(), &uriFactory);
  
    // Create a string that represents a URI.
    HString uriHString;
    hr = uriHString.Set(L"http://www.microsoft.com");
   
    // Create the IUriRuntimeClass object.
    ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClass> uri;
    hr2 = uriFactory->CreateUri(uriHString.Get(), &uri);
   

    dummy = 1;    
}
```

It is the MS example, up to the point of its uri WinRT class construction, and compiles and links and correctly constructs the uri class smart pointer when I leave out my added line that declares the ComPtr for IDeviceWatcherRuntimeClassFactory

The line is my attempt to just create a smart-pointer for the DeviceWatcher class factory, and it fails with identified "IDeviceWatcherRuntimeClassFactory undefined".  (It also fails if I use small "d" as the second letter of the type argument.

In using "IDeviceWatcherRuntimeClassFactory", I'm trying to proceed by exact analogy to the MS example.

Besides the MS online documentation for the DeviceWatcher class ([3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-22000)), which doesn't seem to help me, I've also tried looking at what VS2022 solution explorer shows as the expansion of the header windows.devices.enumeration.h (which also does not seem to be telling me what name to use as far as I can figure out).

I've also tried using the VS2022 Object Browser, pointed to a custom component set of all .winmd files in C:\Windows\System32\WinMetaData, and again the information is not helping me, given my level of knowledge.

Can someone give me a sound method, for an arbitrary WinRT class, to figure out the type to use for the smart pointer to the class factory?

And, to save another iteration, once I can make a smart pointer to the factory, I will
need to make a smart pointer to the class itself (in my case, to DeviceWatcher). Can someone tell me what exact name to use for the ComPtr type?

Thanks.

Comment: DeviceWatcher is not constructible. Instead you call `DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher`. From WRL, this means getting the `IDeviceInformationStatics` from the `DeviceInformation` factory, and then calling one of the `IDeviceInformationStatics::CreateWatcher` methods.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me try proceeding from the information you gave me and see where that gets me.

To help me in the future with other parts of the WinRT API I might need, can you give me any tips on figuring stuff like this out, from the MS documentation alone?  (I see if I looked carefully, the documentation did show me that the uri class has a constructor, but DeviceWatcher does not.  I don't know how I would have figured out the rest of what you told me.)  

There are the example programs, but these are UWP, so the structure confused me -- I only picked up that  I needed a DeviceWatcher!

Comment: X default constructor -> IActivationFactory; X nondefault constructor -> IXFactory; X static members -> IXStatics.

Comment: OK, though for the record I don't think you've countered my belief that the documentation on this part of winRT is not sufficient, unless, possibly, one can go understand the example full programs that the docs might link to., which seem to be both UWP and C++/WinRT rather than simple things like C++ console apps.

Thus, a person needs to understand both UWP and C++/WinRT to use the WinRT API.  (I find the necessary understanding hard to come by--owing to issues of MS documentation of C++/WinRT itself, and of what distortions C++/WinRT produces in the analysis of C++/WinRT code in V Studio.)

Comment: By the way, you're blog looks interesting, and relevant to me as I make an attempt to pull myself up to understanding how to use WinRT (and apparently, I will need to understand C++/WinRT and UWP to understand the examples, which I will apparently need to understand.)

I think it will take a few months!  (As I indicated, MS, in its central docs on C++/WinRT, doesn't seem to state important hints like: "the Solution Explorer views of the version of the WinRT headers that C++/WinRT uses do not represent with WinRT class structure, but rather our complicated kluge of a stuff".)

Comment: One more, on trying to make the C++/WinRT examples easier to understand, when loaded into visual studio.

In central MS documentation for C++/WinRT, I would indicate that the debugger actually attempts to show the actual WinRT classes and their members that the complicated kluge of MS-program-generated C++/winRT headers tries to emulate.  But you have to turn on "natvis".  (Mine was turned off at the default outset of trying to examine the examples.  It seems the debugger , with .natvis on, is a source showing the emulated winRT class structure ).

Comment: The expectation is that people will consume the Windows Runtime through projections (C++/WinRT, C++/CX, JavaScript/WinRT, C#/WinRT, Rust/WinRT, Python/WinRT) and not through the low-level COM ABI. The documentation generally focuses on the projections rather than the ABI. But once you understand the mapping between the ABI and the projection (that I listed above), the rest is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Back to the exact task at hand.

I'm now after a DeviceInformation factory, if I follow your (Raymond's) first comment.

` ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClassFactory> uriFactory;  //works for uri class

ComPtr<IDeviceInformationRuntimeClassFactory> DF1;
ComPtr<IDeviceInformationClassFactory> DF2;
ComPtr<IDeviceInformationActivationFactory> DF3;
ComPtr<IDeviceInformationFactory> DF4;
`
The 4 attempts at a ComPtr all fail.  My first is by exact analogy to the working ComPtr to the Uri Factory. 

What type do I use for the ComPtr for the DeviceInformation factory, and how do figure it out?

Comment: For prior comment, note I do have

#include <windows.devices.enumeration.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;

in my code.

Also note: I tried looking through the solution explorer view of the header contents of windows.devices.enumeration.h  and the header file itself.  I see nothing with "factory".  (Whereas the analogous windows.foundation.h for the uri class had lots of stuff with "factory", including the successfull "IUriRuntimeClassFactory".)

Comment: P.S.  The failure for the ComPtr attempts at a DeviceInformation factory all produce error E0020 "identifier is undefined"

Comment: There is no IDeviceInformationFactory because DeviceInformation has no constructor. Static methods (such as DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher) are on IDeviceInformationStatics

Comment: Ok, got some smart-pointers, but blocked on next step

ComPtr<IDeviceInformationStatics> DevInfoFactory1;
ComPtr<IDeviceInformationStatics> DevInfo1;
both compile and execute.  (But are null pointers).

I try everything I can think of to get the classes, being:

hr4 = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(InterfaceName_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_IDeviceInformation).Get(), &DevInfoFactory1);  

hr2=ActivateInstance(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation).Get(), &DevInfo1);
(continuing)




:

Comment: both of these compile, but the execution of the former returns "class not registered" and the pointer is still null--I kind of expected this, because you said no constructor=no  factory)

but the 2nd returns "not implemented" and the pointer is null.

Do you know what might give me the smart pointer to the class that I want?

(Thanks for your help.  I'm not doing well on my own!)

Comment: You want to call DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher, which a static method on the DeviceInformation runtime class, so it's GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_**DeviceInformation**).Get(), DevInfo1); Classes have activation factories. Interfaces do not have activation factories -- interfaces are abstract; they aren't objects.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that, and then try to maintain a distinction in my mind of when something in the WinRT documentation is a class, and when it is an interface.

(Without understanding how WinRT was set up, I was expecting WinRT to be a set of classes, each implementing one or more interfaces, but was not finding the MS documentation clear on that -- it looked to me like it might be drawing together or muddling the distinction between classes and interfaces.)

I'll try to proceed with your additional information, and see where I next get stuck.  (I surely will get stuck!)

Comment: Hi Raymond:

Following your last 2 comments, I get a compilation failure with just the 2 lines:

ComPtr<IDeviceInformationStatics> DevInfo1;

 GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation).Get(), DevInfo1);

The first gives no compiler error.

That 2nd line, which I copied and pasted from your last comment gives 3 compiler errors:

C2672: GetActivationFacory: no matching overloaded function found

as well as two C2784s.

Comment: C2784 1 being 

C2784 'HRESULT ABI::Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(HSTRING,Microsoft::WRL::Details::ComPtrRef<T>) throw()': could not deduce template argument for 'Microsoft::WRL::Details::ComPtrRef<T>' from 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationStatics>' WRLexample 

C2784 #2 being:

C2784 'HRESULT ABI::Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(HSTRING,T **)': could not deduce template argument for 'T **' from 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationStatics>

Comment: You forgot the `&` on the output parameter. This is just reading the error message and matching it to the function prototype. No Windows Runtime-specific knowledge for that.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond.  Adding the "&" worked (though, for the record, I copied the code without the "&" from your post.)

I appreciate all of your help so far, which it is nice of you to give me for free!

I am thoroughly lost at this point, so to get a working DeviceWatcher, I will apparently need to be guided there all the way, either iteratively or all at once.  I understand you might not have the time or inclination.

(If you don't have the time, I can probably switch off of Visual Studio, which I've been using for 15 or so years, and try QT or even a switched OS if I need to.)  (Contin.)

Comment: So far, these work:

 ComPtr<IDeviceInformationStatics> DevInfoFactory1;
    ComPtr<IDeviceWatcher> myDeviceWatcher;

    GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation).Get(), &DevInfoFactory1);

giving me an apparent non-null Smart Pointer DevInfoFactory1.

Then I am lost.  I don't know if I need to go from DevInfo factory to DevInfo, etc., but have been trying stuff like:

myDeviceWatcher = DevInfoFactory1->CreateWatcher()

(which is roughly taken from MS documentation, with no arguments on the CreateWatcher call) --it fails

Comment: This also fails:

hr = DevInfoFactory1->CreateWatcherDeviceClass();

and I'm thinking of things like this:

hr = DevInfoFactory1->CreateWatcherDeviceClass(&watcher);

but I don't even know how to define watcher.

Comment: Read the function prototype.  `CreateWatcherDeviceClass(DeviceClass deviceClass, IDeviceWatcher** watcher);` So you need to pass two parameters. The first is the device class you want to watch. The second is an output pointer that receives the DeviceWatcher. I think you would be better served using C++/WinRT instead of struggling with the low-level ABI.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond.

I'm going to give up on the WRL method to access WinRT, and try using QT and its development environment, on Windows for now.  (For non-open source use, QT has a hefty licensing fee, but since my stuff is personal or low-volume offered for free, the QT open-sourcing requirement is not an impediment.)

Meanwhile, as for C++/WinRT, I have tried that for the same trial task of accessing bluetooth LE devices, but, the combined complexity of C++/WinRT and the UWP that is in most of the examples makes it too difficult and obscure.   (Will continue.)

Comment: My experience of using C++/WinRT, say the MS example for Bluetooth LE access in C++/WinRT is that there is all this incomprehensible stuff showing up in the solution explorer.

You've got "references", whatever unexplained thing they are.  You've got "external references", which are a mix of ms-supplied headers and also machine-generated headers, generated by C++/WinRT, apparently, and who know whatever else.

There's App.XML, App.cpp, packages.config, packages. some .idl files.  Further, the C++/WinRT structure fakes out a simple c++ object-based API with some kind of inscrutable classes

Comment: (continuing) which aim to present code which looks like there are real c++ classes there, but then degenerates into chaos when you need to debug (and, as I was, are directed by the compiler or linker that the problem is in the ms-software-generated header files, with those complex hard-to-comprehend classes.)

It may be that the problem is poor engineering by MS, perhaps in its desire to have oodles of different technologies and languages over the years, or it might be that just the right book by a smart person who understands the technology in detail can fix the problem.

Comment: It's really not that complicated. The mapping is (1) static method -> IClassNameStatics, (2) default constructor -> IActivationFactory, (3) nondefault constructor -> IClassNameFactory. And at the ABI level, each object is represented by its default interface. That's it. The rest is just standard C++. For example, you misread the function prototype for CreateWatcherDeviceClass and omitted a parameter.

Comment: I am thinking of a book like "Programming Windows 95", Petzold, MS Press.  My copy dated 1996.

What this did is took people who knew how to program batch and non-windowed terminal-run applications, and brought them up to the precise architecture of Windowed Windows application, with the WinMain function, the messages, the message handler functions.

Using the critical information in that book, supplemented only by the Win32 API documentation (which was pretty clear), I've been able to, for maybe 15 or 20 years, produces lots of Windowed programs which work reliably on redistribution.

Comment: The online documentation for UWP and C++/WinRT is inadequate to the task, at least for me.  It's not explaining what I need to know, including exactly what all the stuff I see in the Solution Explorer is doing.

When Win95 came out, MS pointed people to that essential Petzold book.  (And, in fact, had a sample chapter in the online MS documentation.)

Anyway, if you happen to know of such an analogous book or books for WinRT (and perhaps UWP), if you can direct me to it, that might help me if I try to stay with VStudio.

If not, I see Charles Petzold is sill alive.  Give him a ring?

Comment: (In total, analgous books covering all of: C++/WinRT, any additional things you need to know about WinRT to use it fully in C++/WinRT, and UWP.  I am personally trying to avoid UWP apps, as UWP seems to cause a bloat and the documentation says some loss of functionality, but since MS has done most of its WinRT examples in UWP, I guess we have to learn UWP to try to understand the examples.)